# avoid indexing documents again Lucene

Tags: lucene, indexing

When I run my program, I index the documents each time I run the program in eclipse.  However, I want to just index once.  Perhaps by deleting the index after each use, but I don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid reindexing entirely?  Or just trying to avoid creating duplicate documents?

Comment: trying to avoid duplicate documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your IndexWriter to `OpenMode.CREATE`.  It's probably set to `OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND` now.  Setting it to CREATE will cause the existing index at the specified directory to be overwritten when you open the indexwriter, to make way for the new one.

Like:

```java
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(version, analyzer);
config.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
//etc.....
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
```